# AngularJS - changing property value dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm working with an angularjs app and I would like to set one of it's properties dynamically.

This is a piece of my model:

```
    $scope.data_step_3 = {
        'previous_insurance':{
            'label':'Has this type of insurance ever been:',
            'help_text':'',
            'value':'',
            'required':true,
            'regex':''
        },
        'previous_insurance_description':{
            'label':'If so, please explain (not applicable in Missouri):',
            'help_text':'',
            'value':'',
            'required': true,
            'regex':''
        }
}
```

And I would to set  the `required` property of `previous_insurance_description` dynamically. It would the `true` when `previous_insurance.value == 'Non-reviewed'`

How can I do that?

Thanks for any help

Comment: When will the property be changing? If off of user input (i.e a click), you can use ng-click=someFunction() on the respective element. Let someFunction() be responsible for updating that info. If it's coming directly from an API, you could manipulate the values as soon as you receive them with similar logic.

Comment: Your ocntext of code is not very clear. You object come from an api  and when do we change it ?

Comment: @DanKeiger Thanks, you're right. I made it in a ng-click, just this ng-click="data_step_3.previous_insurance_description.required = true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option

HTML:

```
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="x in data_step_3">
 <input value="" ng-model="x.value" ng-keyup="check()">
    <input value="" ng-model="x.label"><br>

  </div>
<span>Required value - {{data_step_3.previous_insurance_description.required}}</span>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data_step_3 = {
        'previous_insurance':{
            'label':'Has this type of insurance ever been:',
            'help_text':'',
            'value':'',
            'required':true,
            'regex':''
        },
        'previous_insurance_description':{
            'label':'If so, please explain (not applicable in Missouri):',
            'help_text':'',
            'value':'',
            'required': true,
            'regex':''
        }
}

    $scope.check=function(){
     var prevInsurance_val= $scope.data_step_3.previous_insurance.value;
      console.log(prevInsurance_val)
     if(prevInsurance_val =="Non-reviewed"){
       $scope.data_step_3.previous_insurance_description.required = false;
      }
      else{
         $scope.data_step_3.previous_insurance_description.required = true;
      }
    }
    console.log()
});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/YWbxpA

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: this option works for the dynamic values as well and for testing I am changing the value from true to false manually..Hope this works for you :)